# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied. when trying to add a user in computer management

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this simple code to add a user in my local machine. I'm getting this exception at newUser.CommitChanges();

Please have a look and suggest me what should I need to do.
Thank you.
var dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + machinename + ", Computer", machineusername, password);

```
        bool IsUserExists = dirEntry.Children.Cast<DirectoryEntry>().Any(d => d.SchemaClassName.Equals("User") && d.Name.Equals(username));
        if (!IsUserExists)
        {
            DirectoryEntry newUser;
            newUser = dirEntry.Children.Add(username, "user");
            newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password });
            newUser.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "FullName", "FullName" });
            newUser.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "Description", "Description" });
            newUser.CommitChanges();
            var sid = new SecurityIdentifier((byte[])newUser.Properties["objectSid"].Value, 0);
            newUser.Close();
            dirEntry.Close();
```

}

Comment: So you think that on Windows every user can add user ?

Comment: Previously my code was working fine. But from few days i'm facing this issue.

Comment: If the same code was working than this is not a programming problem (as this may be problem with rights)

Comment: Can you plz tell me the solution for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running the program as an administrator? If not, then this might solve the issue.

Comment: This solved my issue. After running this program in my visual studio as an administrator it solved.  Thank you so much